# Grunt uglify all .js file into one single file

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed Grunt, Node and updated npm. I am trying to minify all js files into one single file using "grunt uglify". The above command creating new js files with minified code. I placed all JS files in js and also tried with src  folders. Below is my code please help With this, I am new to Grunt:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/js',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'dest/.min.js'
            }]
          }
        },
        cssmin: {
            my_target:{
                files : [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'css/',
                    src: ['*.css', '.min.css'],
                    //src: '*.css',
                    dest: 'css/',
                    ext: '.min.css'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
}
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year since the question was asked, but I'd like to contribute anyway for the sake of googling and finding this thread.

To achieve what you're trying to do you should NOT use `expand` param. Just set `src` and `dest` ones. Like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: [{
                    src: "js/src/*.js",
                    dest: "js/main.min.js"
                }]
            },
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
};
```

Hope this helps.